# Why is there no formulas for converting other bases than 2 to decimal?

Tags: calculus, binary

So to convert a number of any base to its equivalent base 10, you use the formula [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39n10.png) (replacing 2 with an arbitrary number representing the base). But why isn't there any mathematical formula to convert bases like 8 and 16 to base 2? I have only seen people map each digit from base 8 and 16 directly to their corresponding binary digits by looking up a table instead of using a similar smart formula. Shouldn't there be some formula that can be used instead of having to look up a table? If there simply is no such thing, why is that?

Comment: What makes you think there is no formula for base $3$ or whatever? It's just the same: $v=\sum\limits_{i=0}^nb_ik^i$, for base $k$; and this is independent on bases.

Comment: @egreg yea I know that you can replace k with whatever base you want to convert to decimal.. But I wish to convert to binary

Answer (score 2):

There is a formula for any base conversion you can think of, and they all look basically the same. It's just that the most common conversion to learn in school is between binary and decimal. So that's the one everyone knows, that's the one every resource gives a formula for.

That being said, converting between, say, base 2 and base 8 or 16 is particularly easy, and not really worthy of a formula.

Comment: Hmm then why can't I find any formulas that converts bases like 8 and 16 to base 2?

Comment: Because, as I said, that's probably too simple for anyone to bother writing a formula. Converting base 8 or 16 to base 2 is done one digit at the time. For instance, $537_8=101\,011\,111_2$ because $5_8=101_2, 3_8=011_2$ and $7_8=111_2$. This works because $8=2^3$, which implies that one digit base 8 corresponds _exactly_ to three digits base 2.

Comment: Exactly! But you only know what these individual numbers of base 8 represents in binary because you look it up in some table - shouldn't there be a formula for converting, for instance, 5 in base 8 to its binary 101? Like so you can see how it becomes 101? Like you can when converting 5 of base 10 to 0101 by the divide-by-2 algorithm?

Comment: @nichlnss You can easily do it with the exact same formula, if you like. But tell me, if you want to convert $123456789$ to base 100 and find the left-most digit, how would you proceed? The way I think you'd proceed works because 100 is a power of 10. It's the exact same situation.

Answer (score 0):

What you mean a “formula” is something a bit more complicated.

> **Theorem.** *Let $k>1$ be an integer. Then, for each natural number $v$ there exists a largest power $k^n\le v$ and a unique sequence of integers $(b_0,b_1,\dots,b_n)$, with $0\le b_i<k$ such that*
>   $$
> v=\sum_{i=0}^n b_ik^i
> $$

Usually, one chooses different symbols for the integers in the range $[0{\,..\,}k-1]$ and represents the summation above simply by
$$
\widetilde{b_n}\,\widetilde{b_{n-1}}\dots\widetilde{b_1}\,\widetilde{b_0}
$$
where $\widetilde{b_i}$ denotes the chosen symbol. And, most likely, the symbols will be the ones derived from the Indo-Arabic numerals we're accustomed to for the integers from $0$ up to $9$ and possibly uppercase letters beyond those (but it's not necessarily so; some systems such as [*dozenal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duodecimal#Notations_and_pronunciations) use different symbols for 10 and 11).

The theorem above makes no assumption about the representation of $v$; it just *defines* its $k$-adic representation (and states it exists and is unique).

The algorithm for finding the $k$-adic representation is independent on the base we start from:

1. set $i=0$ and $q_0=v$
2. divide $q_i$ by $k$, with quotient $q_{i+1}$ and remainder $b_i$
3. if $q_{i+1}=0$, then stop; otherwise increment $i$ and go to step 2

Comment: Regarding your 3 steps at the bottom - then you still have to convert to decimal (v is the resulting decimal) to convert to another base? This must mean that there in fact is not any formula that convert bases like 8 and 16 DIRECTLY to base 2, right?

Comment: Appreciate the answer btw :)